# What is this gray material/film on the edge of my desk?

Tags: wood, woodworking, mold, furniture, stain

There is this gray material that only appears along the edges of my desk but on both exterior and interior edges. I inspected the desk closely after I first assembled it and did not find this material. I've only had this desk for a month and first noticed it yesterday, so I'm not sure if it will come back after cleaning.

[image: Along interior edge]

[image: Edge under the table top.]

[image: Interior shelf edge]

It is gray, thin and flat, almost like a film. It wipes off with a lysol wipe and looks yellow-green when wiped (last pic). I looked up what the desk is made of and it only says "wood composite" but it looks like particle board and wood veneer or laminate.

[image: Wipes off as yellow-green]

Some have said it's excess glue that the manufacturer didn't clean off, and over time turned from clear to gray by catching dust in my home, but I thought glue (especially dried glue) would not budge unless I use acetone or something like that? I can clean this off with a wet wipe. I also think the textured finish makes it looks like adhesive residue when it might not be (but not 100% sure).

[image: Shiny textured finish]

Someone else said it's mold/mildew but the humidity levels are normal in the room and there has not been any flooding and it hasn't gotten excessively wet (outside of cleaning with wet wipes after I first assembled it). Also, I could be wrong, but I thought mold/mildew and other fungi have circular, spotted growth patterns, at least on wood furniture.

Has anyone experienced something like this before or know what it might be? Any information would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: My first thought was that it was wear from rubbing against it, but it wouldn't be that since it seems to be pretty new and it's in odd places. It could be that the normal oils on your skin have been deposited there and collected some dust, but that doesn't explain up under the desk top, unless it was from handling when you assembled it. TBH, I wouldn't worry about it. You've wiped it off, see if it comes back and if so, how long will it take. Does it wipe off with just a damp paper towel or does it take whatever kind of wet wipe you used?

Comment: Nice photos.  Could it be remnants of packing material?

Comment: Chemicals from poorly manufactured particle board?